# Equivalent to "ask" in capistrano 2.x

Tags: capistrano

I'm trying to write a Capistrano task and would like to ask the user for some input. In Capistrano > 3.2 there's `ask`:

`set :database_password, ask('Enter the database password:', 'default', echo: false)`

(from http://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/user-input/)

Is there an equivalent in Capistrano 2.x? If not, what's the preferred way of doing this?